# Google OAuth Refresh Token Auto Update

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a project whose Publishing status is Testing (I am using Google Ads Api).

```
            using FileStream stream = new("Credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
            // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.

            UserCredential credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
             GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
             scopes,
             "user",
             CancellationToken.None,
             new FileDataStore("Token", true)
            );

            if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock))
                await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
```

When I use the code above, it expects me to log in via Gmail, but I want to automatically handle the Refresh token and continue uninterrupted requests without understanding anything to the user. I am using Desktop Application as Flow, but I am using Net 5 Api as Framework. I look forward to your help in this matter.

Thank you from now.

Comment: The Clint library is storing the refresh token for you all thats done by the library.  If you want to handle its storage yourself you need to create your own implementation of Idatastore, you are currently using the default of filedatastore.   Could you be more clear as to what your issue is exactly?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. After 7 days I need to get Refresh Token again (I send a curl request for this), actually I'm trying to get rid of this situation. @DaImTo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is not with your code the issue is that your app is still in the testing phase.

If you check the docs for [oauth2#expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) you will find it says

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Solution is to set your app to production then your refresh tokens will no longer expire.

[image]

Not sure why you are sending a curl request to get new refresh tokens.  This can all be done with the code you have.

Comment: So what would you recommend if I am developing a product that I cannot Publish (I cannot meet the necessary conditions for now)?

Thank you for your response. @DalmTo

Comment: if your still in development and still testing your app then just reset the refresh token ever week when it expires.    I still don't understand why you are using curl to get your refresh token why not just use the code you have to get your refresh token`?

Comment: By the code I have, do you mean the code in the question or in the documentation? If it is the code in the documents, do you have a chance to send an example?

When I configure the app.config file, I send a curl request after 7 days and get a new Refresh token. Unfortunately, I don't know if there is an alternative solution to this. Thank you for your interest and response in advance. @DalmTo